# How do I make my image a percentage size of another Image in Kivy?

Tags: kivy

I am new to Kivy. My plan will to be to eventually add button behavior and animations to these images. I was wondering how to make my images a certain percentage smaller than another image. 
I have my start button image and I want all button images after that to be smaller than that one.

**start_screen.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class StartScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return StartScreen()

if __name__=='__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.9

<StartScreen>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    background_image: '\kivy\graphics\blu.png'

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.size

        Image:
            id: start_button
            size_hint: .15,.15
            pos:  root.width-300, root.height-40
            source: '\kivy\graphics\start_button.png'
        Image:
            id:usb_button
            size_hint: self.ids.start_button.size_x *.128,self.ids.start_button.size_y*.128
            pos: (20,1)
            source: r'\kivy\graphics\usb_button.png'
```

My first thought was to possibly just make a function in the .py file to do the for the size but I am trying to do most of my app in the kv language. So I am trying to use the ids and properties to calculate the size.

Thanks and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
size_hint: self.ids.start_button.size_x *.128,self.ids.start_button.size_y*.128
```

Set the size_hint to `None, None`, and set `width: start_button.width * 0.128`, and the same for the height.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Another question if i could @inclement? How would i center the widget below with the widget above it? i tried 'x: start_button.center_x' but it aligns the left side the widget with the center of the widget above. What i need is something "Center of my image is equal to center of start_button image"?